# How to create a messagebox with success or the respective Python error message?

Tags: python

I created a script that processes data and saves a file in a location. If the script ran successfully with no errors, I would like to display a message that either says "The task was completed successfully". If there was an error, such as `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'File.xlsx'` then I would like for the actual error to be printed.

I can wrap my script around `try` and then put the error in `except`, I just don't know what to pass it to get the Python error message to show in the box in the `except`.

```
import ctypes

try:
    #Main script
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "The task was completed successfully!", "Success", 1)


except:    
    #If there is an error, display the error.
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "There is an error.", "Failure", 1)
```

If there is a better way, I am definitely open to that. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can use `except as err:` which gives you an exception object as variable `err`

Comment: I get an error when use the syntax `except as err:` and then new line with an indent `ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, err, "Failure",1)`. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: I think I got it. I just did this: `except:
    e = str(sys.exc_info()[0])
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, e, "Failure", 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my desired results with the following.

```
import sys

try:
    #Main Script
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "The reports were processed successfully!", "Success", 0)

except: 
    e = str(sys.exc_info()[0]) ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, e, "Failure", 1)
    types.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, e, "Failure",0)
```